# How to disable Visual Style on tooltip C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, tooltip

How can I disable the visual style only for the tooltip, not for all the application, because if I do so it will change my toolstrip visual style and it will look ugly?

**What I have:**

[image: stupid tooltip]

**What I want:**

[image: better tooltip]

For some reason it just won't work. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Are you create a webpage or a application?

Comment: Have you viewed this documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip

Comment: I saw it already but I can't find any clue on disabling the visual style on the tooltip.

I'm using WinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a WPF solution you'll want to override the default template for the 
ToolTip. Mark Hall's answer is correct if you're looking for a WinForms solution.

**Update:**
Posted this before the comment was added and the question was re-tagged as WinForms. I leave it here for anyone looking for a WPF solution.

XAML:

```
<ToolTip>
    <ToolTip.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness=".5" Padding="5">
                            <TextBlock Text="This is text"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>                                  
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ToolTip.Style>
</ToolTip>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are going to want to look into using the [Tooltip.OwnerDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw.aspx) Property. The example program in the MSDN Link has a style like what you are wanting.